# Android SVG and VML support

Tags: browser, images

Can the Android browser view SVG images in web pages? Can it view VML? Do 3rd party browsers (e.g. Opera) have this ability? If the default or 3rd party browsers don't support it, do they plan on doing so in a later version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, I've only seen two browsers on the Android platform that display SVG.

The Opera Mini browser displays static SVG. It seems to run scripting for a very short period of time, but does not run it continuously. It also does not appear to run SMIL animations.

The Fennec (Firefox Mobile) beta browser also displays static SVG, as well as running scripting. It's still in beta and relatively huge. It doesn't run all of my example scripts successfully, but it does run some. I can not test SMIL animations, because I removed it to free up a large amount of space on my phone.

Comment: Thanks! I inferred from your answer that there is no support in the native browser. Do you know if it's planned?

Comment: The new Opera Mobile browser for Android has better SVG support http://www.appbrain.com/app/opera-mobile-web-browser/com.opera.browser

Comment: For info Fennec is out of beta now and officially called Firefox 4 which was fully released recently. It is now much slimmer and faster than the early betas were. https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Answer (score 2):

I just can add to this, that VML is supported only by Microsoft products (and they will support SVG in ie9), and as you know there is no Microsoft Internet Explorer (or any Microsoft browser) for android :)

VML is still supported in Internet Explorer 9 but Microsoft expects web sites to [transition to SVG](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2e8d87f2-c6ce-491f-a8e1-3413e0cff24a&displaylang=en) in near future.